# Add sub menu to a vertical menu

Tags: html, css

ive added this css onto my vertical menu to create a dropdown...

```
vertical-nav ul li ul{
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:125px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul li{
    background-color:#555555;
    width:125px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li:hover{
    background-color:#333333;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<li><a href="index.php?id=resellers">Staff</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

here is an example JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/3W8kE/

any ideas why its not working? the dropdown menu is constantly displaying

Answer (score 0):

I edited your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/q9eK6/

Just added to the end of your css:

```
.vertical-nav li ul {display: none;}

.vertical-nav li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

And it will work the way you want it. 
Note: I didn't corrected the color and alignment styles.

EDIT: You need to hide the ul inside the li and only show it when you "hover" it.

Comment: how do i change the alignment - ive removed the margin but its still the same?

Comment: You edit the margin and the padding of the li:

.vertical-nav li {
margin: 2px 0;
padding: 5px 0;
}

If you reset to 0 the left and right padding and margin, the inside ul will be aligned with the parent li.

And add to:

.vertical-nav li ul {
display: none;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 6px;
}

The padding 0 because you had a strange padding-left in the inside ul.
The margin-top to keep the ul down at the bottom of the li.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/VBjcV/

Comment: ok cool - when you hover over after this change the whole menu moves down? any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/VBjcV/1/

Comment: and is it possible to make the sub menu items auto auto width so all text can be seen whatever the character length?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WLwxx/
I removed the fixed li width and added to the main ul .vertical-nav.